# Questions about C syntax used in rabbitmq-c

Tags: c++, c, while-loop, rabbitmq, break

I'm looking at [rabbitmq-c](https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c/blob/master/examples/amqp_listen.c), and I noticed the following things:

First, I don't quite understand the usage of outer braces, such as this:

```
  {
    amqp_queue_declare_ok_t *r = amqp_queue_declare(conn, 1, amqp_empty_bytes, 0, 0, 0, 1,
                                 amqp_empty_table);
    die_on_amqp_error(amqp_get_rpc_reply(conn), "Declaring queue");
    queuename = amqp_bytes_malloc_dup(r->queue);
    if (queuename.bytes == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory while copying queue name");
      return 1;
    }
  }
```

Second, take a look at this:

```
  {
    while (1) {
      amqp_rpc_reply_t res;
      amqp_envelope_t envelope;

      amqp_maybe_release_buffers(conn);

      res = amqp_consume_message(conn, &envelope, NULL, 0);

      if (AMQP_RESPONSE_NORMAL != res.reply_type) {
        break;
      }

      printf("Delivery %u, exchange %.*s routingkey %.*s\n",
             (unsigned) envelope.delivery_tag,
             (int) envelope.exchange.len, (char *) envelope.exchange.bytes,
             (int) envelope.routing_key.len, (char *) envelope.routing_key.bytes);

      if (envelope.message.properties._flags & AMQP_BASIC_CONTENT_TYPE_FLAG) {
        printf("Content-type: %.*s\n",
               (int) envelope.message.properties.content_type.len,
               (char *) envelope.message.properties.content_type.bytes);
      }

      amqp_destroy_envelope(&envelope);
    }
  }
```

In my opinion, if AMQP_RESPONSE_NORMAL != res.reply_type, the while loop should break. However, it does not. The break statement acts like a 'continue' statement. Apparently, using 'continue' wouldn't work. Again, I'm not sure why, because as far as I know, a break would cause exiting the while loop.

Answer (score 6):

Braces introduce a compound statement and a new inner scope.

If you define variables inside a compound statement, they're visible only inside that compound statement (between the innermost enclosing `{` and `}`), and, at least in principle, do not exist when that compound statement is not executing.

Also, prior to C99, C did not permit declarations and statements to be mixed. Each block (including the outermost block of a function) had to contain a sequence of zero more more declarations followed by zero or more statements. Creating a new inner block was a way to allow introducing a new variable (whose initial value might depend on previous computations in the function) in the middle of a function. That aspect is no longer necessary, but (a) the code was likely designed to be compilable with pre-C99 compilers, and (b) restricting the scope is likely a good idea anyway.

As for the `break` statement, yes, it does terminate the `while` loop -- and in this case it appears to be the only way the enclosing `while (1)` loop can stop. After the `break;` is executed, execution will continue after the closing `}` of the `while` loop. A `continue` statement would terminate the current iteration of the loop and start again at the top.

Responding to your comment after taking a quick look at the full source, there doesn't seem to be any reason for the outer braces surrounding the while loop. An outline of the source is:

```
int main(int argc, char const *const *argv)
{
    /* ... */
    {                  // <-- Opening outer brace
        while (1) {
            /* ... */
        }
    }                  // <-- Closing outer brace
    /* ... */
}
```

Removing them should have no effect. They could be useful if there were declarations between the opening outer brace and the `while (1)`. Perhaps there were in an earlier version of the code, or perhaps the author anticipates adding something later. The outer braces are harmless but useless.

And since the project is maintained using git, we can look at previous versions of that file. The previous version of `examples/amqp_listen.c` had several declarations at the top of the block, before the `while (1)`. In the current version, those declarations were removed (and some declarations were added at the top of the `while` loop itself, but not the same ones.)

Such minor glitches can easily happen as software is maintained; IMHO this one is not a big deal.

As for the second part of  your question, I don't know why you say the `break` doesn't terminate the loop. Could it be that the loop is simply entered again? (I can't tell without studying the rest of the code.)

Comment: in the code above, is there any reason to use outer braces? If the while loop runs forever, the only two variables res and envelope should be automatically destroyed when the loop restart.